# Adding Methods Mongoose Schema w/NestJS

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I need a transformation method attached to my Schema type. How can I accomplished with without duplicating code? If I remove the class method`asGrpcProgram` I get the following error:

`src/programs/programs.controller.ts:129:30 - error TS2339: Property 'asGrpcProgram' does not exist on type 'Program'.`

If I remove the function expression assigned to `ProgramSchema.methods.asGrpcProgram` I get the following error when the method is invoked at runtime:

`ERROR [RpcExceptionsHandler] program.asGrpcProgram is not a function`

```js
import { grpc } from 'lis-protobuf';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Program extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  externalId: string;

  @Prop([String])
  skillIds: string[];

  public asGrpcProgram(): grpc.Program {
    const { id, name, externalId, skillIds } = this;
    return { id, name, externalId, skillIds };
  }
}

export const ProgramSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Program);

ProgramSchema.methods.asGrpcProgram = function (): grpc.Program {
  const { id, name, externalId, skillIds } = this;
  return { id, name, externalId, skillIds };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64378062/12604568), you can just:

```
import { grpc } from 'lis-protobuf';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Program extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  externalId: string;

  @Prop([String])
  skillIds: string[];

  asGrpcProgram: Function;
}

export const ProgramSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Program);

ProgramSchema.methods.asGrpcProgram = function (): grpc.Program {
  const { id, name, externalId, skillIds } = this;
  return { id, name, externalId, skillIds };
};
```

Note: If the error persists after the above approach, try [this](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/issues/408#issuecomment-741491739) one.